# Delphi 2010 - [Fatal Error] Parameter "write" cannot be null

Tags: windows-10, delphi-2010

Используемый софт:

- Embarcadero Delphi 2010 v14.0.3593.25826
- Install файл: Embarcadero.Delphi.2010.RTM.v14.0.3615.26342.Lite.v3.8.exe
- Windows 10 Pro 1909

При попытке скомпилировать проект/пакет вылетает ошибка `[Fatal Error] Parameter "write" cannot be null`. Устанавливал и в "Programm Files" и в другие директории, проблема не исчезает. Пробовал ставить другие версии Delphi, у них нету такой проблемы. Нужна именно эта версия, под нее надо реанимировать проекты. Ранее ею (инсталятор тотже) пользовался, но на Windows 7.

P.S. версия Delphi в About не совпадает в наименовании инсталятора.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: что за `lite` там в инсталлере у вас?

Comment: Инсталятор пишет: Lite v3.8

Comment: я что-то не припомню, чтобы эмбаркадеро выпускали какой-то lite делфи. Стартер появился позже 2010й.

Comment: Насколько я понял их маркировку продуктов - lite это без билдера и .net, не RAD Studio, только delphi без разных там корпоративных интеграций. Поэтому и идут две версии: одна это версия ядра Delphi и другая для Lite. Пример: Embarcadero Delphi 11.2 v28.0.46141.0937 Lite v17.2

Comment: да нет таких официальных версий. ставьте нормальную среду, а не урезанную кем-то. Билдер можете не ставить, он там отключается. Всегда версии были обычная, про, энтепрайз и архитект, потом еще стартер/комьюнити сделали, и все.